# HTTPS Everywhere vs. NoScript

Tags: tls

What does HTTPEverywhere gives compared to NoScript with Firefox (Options|Advanced|HTTPS|Behavior)?

Why use HTTPEverywhere, when NoScript also can strict websites to use only HTTPS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTTPS Everywhere uses an EFF produced whitelist of sites and rules to use and can have rules like redirecting wikipedia.org to secure.wikipedia.org.

NoScript has only a user defined whitelist of domains and no such rule abilities.

Answer (score 2):

From the developers of HTTPS Everywhere eff.org website:

> HTTPS Everywhere aims to have a simpler user experience than NoScript, and to support complex rewriting rules that allow services like Google Search and Wikipedia to be redirected to HTTPS without breaking anything.

For more details visit this link [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Difference is HTTPS everywhere will use HTTPS when it is available, NOSCRIPT says only use HTTPS period. So it appears to me if the site doesn't have HTTPS you wouldn't be able to view it with NOSCRIPT. You can however whitelist from site to site of course this is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Both are white list approaches.

Comment: No script's is manual not automatic like https everywhere

Comment: Yes and no. HTTPS Everywhere uses a list it downloads from EFF's servers, it's still manually edited by someone at the EFF.

Answer (score -1):

I use both at times, but my favorite tool for this job is HTTPS Finder. It probes the sites you visit for HTTPS support, and can swap you over whenever HTTPS is available. It can also write the HTTPS Everywhere rules for you.

Comment: This really doesn't answer anything.. It should have been a comment.